# Spring Cloud Gateway and Oauth2 Server response exception url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Gateway config:
bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: tools-gateway
  cloud:
    nacos:
      config:
        server-addr: tools-nacos:9999
        group: DEFAULT_GROUP
        prefix: tools-gateway
        file-extension: yaml
      discovery:
        server-addr: tools-nacos:9999
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: tools-uaa
#          uri: lb://tools-uaa
          uri: http://tools-nacos:8001
          predicates:
            - Path=/auth/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1
  profiles:
    active: dev
```

port 8443

access url:http://localhost:8443/auth/username
response url:
[image]

access url:http://localhost:8001/auth/username

is success

Comment: Can you please describe in detail what is happening?

Comment: I configured the route for the 8001 service on the Gateway. Now I forward it through the gatway, requesting 8843/auth/. Actually I should jump to 8001/auth/, but now I jumped to 8080/login.